# SSRS SubReport - Set to Not Grow, but it continues to grow

Tags: reporting-services, size, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, subreport

I am building out a report that contains a Sub Report, I need that Sub Report to be a static size. I've researched and read that you can place it in a tabix and set the row CanGrow to False. However, as soon as I put the sub report in the row, the tablix automatically resets CanGrow to True.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get around this? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am at a loss right now and can't seem to figure it out.

[image: This is what I want to accomplish.]

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent it from showing the whole subreport. But, you can pass the subreport a parameter. And that parameter could be a flag that controls how much of it is visibile. So, when the subreport is viewed from the main one, you could have it cut off where you want. Then when it's viewed by itself have that parameter default to show everything.

Comment: The issue is, I know I can't limit it from showing the whole report. I want to try and contain it in a smaller window though that has scroll bars instead of it growing to an obscene amount of rows. If you gather what I am saying.

And I am passing it a parameter from the Parent Report.

Comment: @ItalianStallion4215 Is there a reason why you don't want to try conditional visibility as I suggested?

Comment: I need all the results, not a cut off portion, This is for a search type report. User puts ID in parameter, and the query pulls back all results for that. However, the results are in the 100's, so the report becomes like 40 something pages long. I want to be able to contain the results in a scroll-able area. See picture I attached to my question. At this point I am almost thinking I'll need to build a C# program instead.

Comment: @ItalianStallion4215 Yeah, there's no support for a scrollbar like that in SSRS.

Comment: Yeah, I decided to build a C# application instead. A little more work and coding, but in the long scheme of things, will probably be much better.